# Salesforce Marketing Cloud -> How to pass the email adress to existing Webform

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I need a form (in Wordpress) that submits the email address I entered to the Marketing Cloud newsletter subscription page. This way the system should recognize if it is a new registration or an existing contact.

Basically a field "E-Mail" address and the button "send" afterwards opens a new page with the Salesfroce registration form.

**Screenshot example Form**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSHNz.png

**After click on send, a new site will open for checking the e-mail:**

[https://cloud.marketing.mysite.com/newsletter?ekey=[the](https://cloud.marketing.mysite.com/newsletter?ekey=%5Bthe) subscribers’s E-Mail address]

**This is the form action:**

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

This should work. cloud pages in Marketing cloud can check if a Query Parameter with Ekey exists, if it does , ut can access the value and save it in a DE.